# How to get all users with role in Azure Ad using graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How I can get all users with roles related to azure ad app using Graph API

Endpoint

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{app-id}/appRoleAssignedTo
```

Code

```
var appRoleAssignedTo = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["{app-id}"]
                               .AppRoleAssignedTo
                               .Request()
                               .GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven't create an authProvider instance. please create it first and follow below code, please check the docs for more details .

Code:
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var appRoleAssignments = await graphClient.ServicePrincipals["{servicePrincipal-id}"].AppRoleAssignments
.Request()
.GetAsync();

[image]

Reference doc- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp